# Find all computers on network using NetServerEnum()

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

Am trying to find all computers on network. The following code is working fine for Win7-32bit, but giving following error for Win7-64bit.

`NetServerEnum()` is returning code -6118.

```
public sealed class NetworkBrowser
{
    [DllImport("Netapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute]
    public static extern int NetServerEnum(
        string serverName,
        int dwLevel,
        ref IntPtr pBuf,
        int dwPrefMaxLen,
        out int dwEntriesRead,
        out int dwTotalEntries,
        int dwServerType,
        string domain,
        out int dwResumeHandle
        );

    [DllImport("Netapi32", SetLastError = true), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    public static extern int NetApiBufferFree(IntPtr pBuf);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct ServerInfo100
    {
        internal int sv100_platform_id;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        internal string sv100_name;
    }

    public static ArrayList GetNetworkComputers()
    {
        ArrayList networkComputers = new ArrayList();
        const int MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH = -1;
        int SV_TYPE_WORKSTATION = 1;
        int SV_TYPE_SERVER = 2;
        IntPtr buffer = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr tmpBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;
        int entriesRead;
        int totalEntries;
        int resHandle;
        int sizeofInfo = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(ServerInfo100));


        try
        {
            int ret = NetServerEnum(null, 100, ref buffer,
                                    MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH, out entriesRead, out totalEntries,
                                    SV_TYPE_WORKSTATION | SV_TYPE_SERVER, null, out resHandle);

            if (ret == 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < totalEntries; i++)
                {
                    tmpBuffer = new IntPtr((int)buffer +(i * sizeofInfo));

                    ServerInfo100 svrInfo = (ServerInfo100)
                                               Marshal.PtrToStructure(tmpBuffer,
                                                                      typeof(ServerInfo100));
                    networkComputers.Add(svrInfo.sv100_name);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            NetApiBufferFree(buffer);
        }
        return networkComputers;
    }
}
```

I've Googled a lot for it, but haven't found any solution for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I think, this answers your question exactly.

[Retrieving a list of network computer names using C# - Code project article comment](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16113/Retreiving-a-list-of-network-computer-names-using?msg=4766948#xx4766948xx)

> Bug and resolution - designmaistro - 25-Feb-14 23:46
>
> I've read, that some people had an issue using this piece of code on x64 based systems. It is probably related to pointer operations, more precisely this line is where the code breaks:
>
> `tmpBuffer = new IntPtr((int)buffer + (i * sizeofINFO));`
>
> Because on x64 systems the address space is 64 bits in width, the code should be changed to the following:
>
> `tmpBuffer = new IntPtr((long)buffer + (i * sizeofINFO));`
>
> After this change everything should work fine.
> Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

may be this will help

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1107608f-ef56-4719-a5e5-f6966d111043/win32-api-compatibility-on-windows-7-64-bit?forum=winforms

it says
"When youset the Target Platform of your application is 'AnyCPU', byt default it will run in 64bit mode on 64bit machines and runs in 32 bit mode on 32bit machines. Now, assume that your app is running in 64 bit mode and at some point of time, it has to invoke some API or code that is specific to 32 bit machines (like your PrintDlg API). But, since your process is already running in 64 bit mode, your 32 bit code cannot be loaded and hence it will fail.

Byt setting Target platform to x86 - your application will always run in 32 bit mode on both 32 & 64 bit machines. Since, the application is always running in 32 bit mode, your 32 bit components or API can also be invoked without any problem. Now, the only problem is - if you have any 64bit specific component, it cannot be invoked (because 64 bit code cannot be run in 32 bit process). But I don't think this can be a problem to you are designing your app specifically for 64 bit machines."

Comment: I tried to build using all platform targets -Any CPU, x86. But still its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your function was worked completely by using this annotation :

```
[DllImport("Netapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
```

instead :

```
[DllImport("Netapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute]
```

Regards.

Answer (score -1):

int ret = NetServerEnum(null, 100, ref buffer,
                                    MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH, out entriesRead, out totalEntries,
                                    SV_TYPE_WORKSTATION | SV_TYPE_SERVER, null, out resHandle);

You need to pass domainname to the initialization
int ret = NetServerEnum(null, 100, ref buffer,
                                    MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH, out entriesRead, out totalEntries,
                                    SV_TYPE_WORKSTATION | SV_TYPE_SERVER, **domainName**, out resHandle);

And it works perfectly

Thanks